# Login with Facebook Php Sdk for returning users

Tags: php, facebook

Currently I am using facebook's php ask to login to my website. When they signup, I am storing their email address fetched from facebook. When they return on website and login through facebook, the fb email is matched with the one present in database and if matched, user is logged in.

But that's not a good practice. Because if user changed email in future, he/she couldn't login and also if user changed email address to someone's, it will let him/her log in.

I have found that we can store user access token, but it is not permanent. If anyone knows how we can achieve this with better security, it would be a great help.

Comment: You will not even get an email from every FB user … So use their FB id (the app-scoped user id) to identify them, and only that. (And store and handle it as text, not as an integer.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store and use user [FB UID](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user). This UID is permanent and unique for every user.

Also if UID is not present in your system than you can try to find this user in your DB by the email. If user with the given email is found then you can stores link "user_id_in_your_system" and UID. Next login will be processed by the given UID.

Keep in mind that some users can deny email permission for the your site

Comment: small addition: it will be an "app scoped id" now, so the id will be unique for every user BUT you will get a different one in another app. you don´t get the global id anymore. just to clarify this further, the answer is correct, of course :)

Comment: I am getting user id in Php Sdk using // `$userId = $facebook->getUser();`, is this what you talking about?

Comment: Uday Hiwarale, yes.

@luschn, FB says: __If you need to map the same user IDs across multiple apps or run cross-app promotions, we've added a new API called the Business Mapping API. This lets you map a logged-in user's IDs across apps as long as those apps are all owned by the same business. Learn more about implementing cross-promotions.__ -https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading

Comment: i know that, but that´s another story and you still get different IDs per app.